# Express Server Restart does not load changes in React Components from JSX files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, ts-node

We have the following setup:

NodeJS express server that renders a document from React components defined in .tsx files. The html is used to generate PDF files on the server side.

We use ts-node-dev in order to detect changes in the typescript files (.ts and .tsx files), and to reload the server.

Now we have the problem that changes in the .tsx files are detected, and I see the following log entry:

```
[INFO] 17:27:03 Restarting: /Users/.../file.tsx has been modified
```

However, when I trigger the PDF generation again, the changes I made in the .tsx files to the react components are not reflected, I only see them after I kill ts-node-dev and start the server again manually.

Any ideas why the components are sticky? Is there a way how I can make sure they get reloaded?

**Our setup:**

- Node v10.16.0
- express: 4.17.1
- react: ^16.8.6
- react-dom: ^16.8.6
- ts-node: ^8.3.0
- typescript: 3.5.2
- ts-node-dev: 1.0.0-pre.40

Comment: have you tried to use hot-reload?

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to do that? I found lots of information for webpack, but we're not using that since it's only server-side. There is one plugin for babel, but I was not able to get babel running with our current project.